# Bounding the inverse of a diagonally dominant matrix entry-wise

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

I have a $d \times d$ matrix $A$ whose entries are bounded (C1): $I - \epsilon X \preceq A \preceq I + \epsilon X$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $X = 11^\top - I$ is  the matrix with ones everywhere but the diagonal. Furthermore, $\epsilon < 1/d$, so $A$ is guaranteed to be diagonally dominant and thus non-singular.

1. Firstly, is the following true (C2): $(I + \epsilon X)^{-1} \preceq A^{-1} \preceq (I - \epsilon X)^{-1}$?
2. If not, does there exist an $\epsilon'$ such that $c(I - \epsilon' X) \preceq A^{-1} \preceq c(I + \epsilon' X)$ for some constant, $c$?

Empirically, it seems like the first statement is true: I generated a few 1,000 matrices $A$ satisfying the bound (C1) and observed that (C2) holds always. Assuming that the first statement is true, I have been able to prove the second statement for an $\epsilon' \approx \epsilon/(1 - \epsilon d)$.

Note that $A \preceq B$ if is $B - A$ contains only positive entries; it is not the Loewner ordering.

Comment: If $A \preceq B$, then $A^{-1} \succeq B^{-1}$ as the inverse map is order reversing....

Comment: I feel that you make a confusion between two orderings : entrywise or Loewner.

Comment: @suvrit: Hmm... I know the order reversing property to be true for the Loewner ordering. Is it also true for the entrywise ordering?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A\leq B$ be true iff $B-A$ contains only non-negative entries (with your definition $I-\epsilon X\leq A\leq I+\epsilon X$ is impossible). You have a big problem with the diagonals of the matrices.

Clearly 1. is false. 
 Take $d=2$ and $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&a\\b&1\end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)$. Then $(I+\epsilon X)^{-1}\leq A^{-1}\leq (I-\epsilon X)^{-1}$ implies $1/(1-\epsilon^2)\leq 1/(1-ab)\leq1(1-\epsilon^2)$ and then $ab=\epsilon^2$, that is contradictory.

Clearly 2. is false. Indeed $c(I-\alpha X)\leq A^{-1}\leq c(I+\alpha X)$ implies $c\leq 1/(1-ab)\leq c$, that is contradictory ($ab$ goes through $(-\epsilon^2,\epsilon^2)$).